# Building combobox with Linq - giving error because multiple entries for same key

Tags: c#, linq, distinct-values

I try to get a list of all Zipcodes from tblAccomodation to put in a combobox.

e.g.
8630 - Veurne
8660 - De Panne
8670 - Koksijde

This is the relation between the 2 tables:
tblCity.ID = tblAccomodation.CityID

TblCity contains (ID, Zipcode, Name, UpName, StructCode)
TblAccomodation contains (ID, CityID, Name, .....)

Off course there are multiple Accomodations with the same CityID so I've tried to use DISTINCT(). But it's not working.

```
public static Dictionary<int, string> getPostals()
{
    Dictionary<int, string> Zipcodes = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    var AllAccomodations = (from oAccomodation in new DBReservationDataContext().tblAccomodations
                          orderby oAccomodation.Name ascending
                          select oAccomodation).ToList();

    foreach (tblAccomodation item in AllAccomodations.Distinct())
    {
        Zipcodes.Add(item.CityID, clsCities.getCityInfo(item.CityID, "Zipcode") + ' ' + clsCities.getCityInfo(item.CityID, "UpName"));
    }
    return Zipcodes;
}
```

What do I need to change?

Answer (score 1):

`Distinct` compares `oAccomodation` objects, what you need is comparison of CityID's

You can use [morelinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)'s [DistinctBy](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs?r=f4c39a771d712a568467eaa31840cc22e07a5ed0) since you already have `AllAccomodations` in memory.

```
foreach (tblAccomodation item in AllAccomodations.DistinctBy(x=>x.CityID))
```

or

```
foreach (tblAccomodation item in AllAccomodations.GroupBy(x => x.CityID)
                                                 .Select(g => g.First()))
```

Comment: that is indeed a possibility, but I just switched the whole query. I've started querying in tblCity with the condition from tblAccomodation. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static Dictionary<int, string> getPostals()
    {
        Dictionary<int, string> oZipcodes = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        DBReservationDataContext oDBConnection = new DBReservationDataContext();

        var vAllCities = (from oCity in oDBConnection.tblCities
                          where (from oAccomodation in oDBConnection.tblAccomodations
                                 select oAccomodation.CityID).Contains(oCity.ID)
                          select oCity).Distinct();

        foreach (tblCity item in vAllCities)
        {
            oZipcodes.Add(item.ID, clsCities.getCityInfo(item.ID, "Zipcode") + ' ' + clsCities.getCityInfo(item.ID, "UpName"));
        }
        return oZipcodes;
    }
```